# Regex to capture range of floats (3.0 – 5.5)

Tags: javascript, regex

I can’t figure out a regex to capture a float between 3.0 and 5.5.

This is what I have so far: `/^[3-5]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/`.

Comment: Don't forget to show your attempts

Comment: I have this so far:

`/^[3-5]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/`

Comment: are you sure you need regex for this? how about parseFloat? can you specify why you need that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well range and regex don't go hand in hand. But since your range is smaller. This will work.

**Regex:** `\b([3-4]\.[0-9]|5\.[0-5])\b`

**Explanation:**

- `[3-4]\.[0-9]` will match from `3.0` to `4.9`.
- `5\.[0-5]` will match from `5.0` to `5.5`.
- `\b` on both sides won't allow numbers to be preceded or followed.

**For checking complete string to be in range specified you can use:** [`^([3-4]\.[0-9]|5\.[0-5])$`](https://regex101.com/r/vA6zV3/4)

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vA6zV3/6)**</kbd>

Comment: You should add some kind of boundaries, or this will match 3.2 from 13.2. Also floats might have more than just 1 decimal place.

Comment: @SebastianProske: You are right about boundaries. I will add it now. OP didn't specified more that one decimal place though. So I kept it till one place.

Comment: `[^\d]` could match one space. As @SebastianProske suggested, it could be improved by `\b([3-4]\.[0-9]|5\.[0-5])\b`.

Comment: @ccf: Done ! Thanks.